# Can I use Kickflip with Parse to stream video TO server from Android device during recording

Tags: parse-platform, video-streaming, kickflip

Parse is turning out to be convenient to use. However the service does not allow for streaming videos to the server. I need a service that allows my users to stream videos to the server while they are recording. I was able to find the KickFlip SDK. Does anyone know how I might be able to pair KickFlip with Parse for Video Streaming? Even if I were to use both services, as opposed to just the KickFlip SDk, how would I coordinate the two? Parse provides rich social database but storing a ParseFile video is limiting (no streaming and 10MB max).

Answer (score 0):

Should work on a REST client with a normal POST ( i would not do your scenario without adding something like Heroku/EC2 to parse.com PAAS architecture, but it will work )... I dont know 'flipkick' but you must know low-level protocol details b4 you include this in a solution.

In REST.POST.Headers you would need to include the combo of header values consistent with a client posting a stream on https to parse.( [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371201/how-to-stream-response-body-with-apache-httpclient/27460293#27460293) ). ie NO length header, ask for chunked encoding, use http 1.1.  On a FILE POST to parse, IMO you dont need to worry about a timeout. You will have to append to the end of your posted bytestream the normal http , chunked-encoding , [byte sequence signifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) END_OF_DATA.

[Sample Curl interaction](http://pastebin.com/juZcNidK) with headers etc.

Observe relevant parse.file.sz. limitations...