# Continuous response from REST api

Tags: scala, web-services, rest, scalatra

I want to read logs from server until a certain time and return via an api endpoint (e.g., like `tail`). Since the file can be long, I want to return some output continuously

Is it possible to return some output continuously or does one api call only returns *discretely* in one step?

FWIW, I am using `scalatra`.

Comment: What you are looking for is called _chunked response_. I don't have any experience with Scalatra, but perhaps this will help you: https://gist.github.com/rwalk/3b4dc9524b2383a9645d3d88a2e820d9

Comment: @Grant you are probably right. Let me experiment with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371201/how-to-stream-response-body-with-apache-httpclient

Comment: I'm not sure why would you need a http client? If I understand your question correctly, you want to continuously stream a file from the server. By the way, you might also want to have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream